# How set full screen width background on fixed width element?

Tags: css, layout

I have simple structure of element container of **dynamic height** and **fixed width** (*Markup* below). On one hand the element's background should span the whole window width, on the other the children's size must be limited by the container (*Desired layout* below). The number of children and their sizes (which are equal on the image only for simplicity) are dynamic.

Is that possible without adding extra container? I want to avoid achieving the desired element content width by setting `width` on the children, because their number is dynamic and the size relationships become complicated to write unless their total width is already limited by container's `width`.

Here's a [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/brVxWp) to experiment;

*Markup*

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
  <div class="child">
  ...
</div>

.container {
  width: <fixed-width>px;
}
```

*Desired layout* (the whitespace between children and container is irrelevant)
[image: Desired layout]

Comment: Why not use Flexbox? In this instance you could use: `justify-content: space-around;` for the children classes and they would be even throughout with an equal gap between them

Comment: @Option Because I need the children total width to be limited by some fixed width. I don't know how to achieve that with Flexbox without using extra wrapper container.

Comment: You'd simply set a max width within the class that requires the width restriction.

Comment: @Option: But I'd need to set `max-width` on children then, which I said I wanted to avoid. That is because there are few different children layouts, in which the children have different size relationships, which are much easier to describe when having `width` already set on the container.

Comment: Let me throw something together, I think you're missing what I suggested,

Comment: @Option: How is it going? :)

Comment: @Robert - my apologies, the previous code I gave you didn't work because I completely misunderstood your intentions (completely my fault). I've got a semi work-around that I'll post up for you now as a new post  :)

Comment: @Frits: No problem :). I'll be waiting then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One route we can take to solve this is by using viewport width on the parent container padding, to **force** the children into a box that is only 500px wide (as per your codepen).

The important thing to remember when doing this is that `box-sizing:border-box;` will need to be set on the container, otherwise the `padding` goes ballistic.

We do this by using `calc`, `vw` and `padding`.

```
padding: 20px calc(50vw - /*half of container width*/);
```

Here's the full expanded code of your container on the linked codepen:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px calc(50vw - 250px);
  background-color: #acffac;
  background-size: 100vw auto;
  background-position: center top;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  overflow-y:scroll; /* fixes potential calculation errors caused by scroll bar - thanks to Roberts comment */
}
```

[Here's a working version of the codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YxyORz), and for the sake of keeping all my eggs in one basket, here's an expandable code snippet:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px calc(50vw - 250px);
  background-color: #acffac;
  background-size: 100vw auto;
  background-position: center top;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.child {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ff4444;
}

.child+.child {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

I will finish off by pointing out that if someone else has a better solution, you may want to look at that for time being instead as there is some issues with using `vw` inside `calc` on older versions of [Chrome and Safari](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).

---

**EDIT:**

As noted in the comments by Vadim and Robert there are a few things that can cause some snags.

Firstly, assuming you are working with a bare minimum template (i.e. no normalize/reset.css), your body will most probably still have the inherent margins that would mess with this kind of layout. You can fix this with:

```
body {
    margin:0;
}
```

Secondly, depending on your OS (Yes I'm looking at you Microsoft!) your scrollbars can push your content to the side whilst simultaneously still being included in the calculation for `vw`.

We can fix this one of two way. The first being an adjustment on the padding calculation to include the scrollbar side, but you would have to write a script to ensure that scrollbar is actually present, **and** scrollbars differ in sizes (I.E -> 17px, Edge -> 12px).

The other alternative would be to use a custom content scroller, which would do a full `overflow:hidden;` over the content, thereby removing the scroll bar, before implementing it's own version of a scrollbar (which generally lies on top of the content with a `position:fixed;`) it.

Comment: I __think__ that I understood your question correctly, let me know if this helps?

Comment: If `100vw` won't add horizontal scrollbar, then it'll be exactly what I need. I need to test that.

Comment: It doesn't work for me or I am missing something. Check out the pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VzvGbN

Comment: If you have a fixed width, the background won't extend above that width.

Comment: @Robert - I've edited my answer - go ahead and let me know how it works out for you - there's an added codepen (forked from the one you gave me) with a working example :)

Comment: @Kangouroops yes - you are very right. It's because I completely misread the question 0_o. I have since adjusted my answer, my apologies for the confusion :)

Comment: @Frits: It works now. I was worried about setting any size to `100vw`, because that usually sets unwanted horizontal scrollbar, but fortunately not in case of backgrounds. I also missed the fact that you can set `padding` in `vw` and use `calc` there. Thanks Frits :).

Comment: Not a problem at all :) Yeah, I've had issues with it myself before, but luckily in this instance it works out :) Glad I could help!

Comment: @Frits Great! Just one more minor thing to ensure block has `500px` you should set `body { margin: 0; }` or take into account `body` `margin`s when calculating `padding`s.

Comment: I found an issue with that solution (you might add an information about that in your post): the width of the container is not pixel perfect. That is because, when the vertical srollbar appears on the page, `50vw` padding is half of that scrollbar width more than it should be and so the resuling `width` of the container becomes smaller than intended one (which is calculated fine when there is no vertical srollbar). Unfortunately it makes the solution unusable on my site, where I need that column to have the size set properly down to 1 pixel. Again shame on how `vw` unit has been standardized...

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov thanks for that! I've popped it in :)

Comment: @Robert Thanks - I've also added details about that along with possible avenues to approach the problem with. :)

Comment: @Frits Thanks. Regarding your note I don't think OS has anything to do with the problem, nor has particular browser. `vw` unit is standarized so that the browsers should calculate `100vw` as visible area + scrollbar width (or more precisely of area which is underneath the scrollbar). I'm currently running Firefox on Arch Linux and it displays the same problem.

Comment: @Robert to be honest, I only ever have this sort of problem on Windows (however I haven't been on a standard *nix distro in years). On my Mac, the OS by default hides the scrollbar until you scroll. Because of that, it lays __on top__ of the content, and never has to be calculated for when working with vw. It is probably wrong to blame MS for it though :P

Comment: @Frits Is it Mac or Safari browser? Does Firefox and Chrome also hide the scrollbar on OS X? On Linux they don't.

Comment: @Robert definitely Firefox (my default browser). I would have to double check Chrome & Safari when I go into the studio on Monday, but I am almost certain that it's the same on there.

Comment: @Frits Today I figured out that setting `html { overflow-y: scroll; }` fixes the issue with the scrollbar. Then the whole layout is pixel perfect. I propose adding that to your answer.

Comment: @Robert awesome - I've added that in :) Thanks for the heads-up :)

Answer (score 1):

Using vw and flex we can center the child elements and achieve exactly what you require. I have written a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atif_hassan/fugtr03e/) where you can check it out.

Basically what I have done is created a container with display set to flex. Using margin property of the first child element, I have centered all of the other child divs and then the regular properties were added to other divs.

Here's the code

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container{
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 40vw;
  background-color: #333333;
  align-items: center;
}

.child{
  width: 4vw;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 10vw;
}

.child:first-child{
  margin-left: 28vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I suppose you've missed many points in question. Please read it carefully.

Comment: It assumes number and size of the children are known, but they are not. I clarified the question by adding information that the number and sizes of children are dynamic.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that. I will get on with it then.